# List item long press transition

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onlongclicklistener, long-press

This is what I use for list item selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<!-- normal -->
</selector>
```

I have enabled a context menu for the `ListView` items so a users can long click on an item. What I want is that when a user long clicks an item, the colour should change from green to red. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use a [`Transition(Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition) to accomplish this. For a real-life example, have a look at the [transition](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/res/drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml) that is part of the list selector in ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list_selector_background as it, As suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/nookdevs/source/browse/trunk/nookLibrary/res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml?spec=svn29&r=29)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
        <!--
                Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so
                the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state.
        -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
                android:state_pressed="true"     android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
        <item android:state_focused="true"
                android:drawable="@+drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />
</selector>
```

And use a transition for long press, As suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/nookdevs/source/browse/trunk/customLibrary/res/drawable/list_selector_background_transition.xml?r=23):-

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_pressed"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_longpress"  />
</transition>
```

May be it will help you..

Comment: did you figure it out? I am having the same problem, the code looks good but the transition is not happening, only the first color in it is used on long press.